# How to align text with prefixIcon in textformField flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I am adding `prefixIcon` in `textFormField` but it is not aligning. I used `contextPadding` also and wrapped `Icon` with `padding` but its not working. Also I have seen that `prefixIcon` works like stack as shown in picture. I have used all possible ways mentioned below:

**By wrapping with padding**

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
      child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
    ),
    prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: 08, maxWidth: 08, minHeight: 0, minWidth: 0),
```

**By contentPadding**

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
```

[image]

Comment: can you add full TextFormFiled that you are working on

Answer (score 0):

Do  `flutter clean` and restart the app, and you can check these examples.

[image]

**Test Code**

```
Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "normal",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "textFormField wrapped with padding",
                    alignLabelWithHint: true,
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.usb_rounded),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "contentPadding, horizontal: 10, vertical: 10 ",

                  /// Use  same pading
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.safety_divider),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "contentPadding, horizontal: 21, vertical: 40 ",

                  /// Use  same pading
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21, vertical: 40),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.safety_divider,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "contentPadding,only(left: 10) ",

                  /// Use  same pading
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.safety_divider,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText:
                      "contentPadding,.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),",

                  /// Use  same pading
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.safety_divider,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

First run command `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` then try to below code hope its help to you.

declare your controller:

```
  TextEditingController emailscon = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contact = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController conpassword = TextEditingController();
```

Your Widget below

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: emailscon,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  labelText: 'Name',
                  hintText: 'Enter Name Here',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: contact,
                obscureText: obsecureText,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  hintText: 'Enter Password Here',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: password,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  hintText: 'Enter Email Here',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: conpassword,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                  labelText: 'Contact',
                  hintText: 'Enter Contact Here',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Your Screen look like-> [image]

Comment: you are using outlinedborder. But I want to make this work with underlinedBorder()

Comment: @ArslanKaleem please check my updated answer hope it help to you , I just removed border of the TextFormField